# Pass multiple query parameter values with clj-http

Tags: clojure, twilio, clj-http

I need to make a web request to an external service (Twilio), with multiple values specified for the same parameter, e.g.

```
GET /some-url?status=1&status=2&status=3
```

How do I tell clj-http to encode the request like this?

Answer (score 4):

You can put multiple values for your `:query-param` value inside of [`sequential`](https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http/blob/3da50bf531938f09cdfd27cca11a2b8f1d9fa356/src/clj_http/client.clj#L624):

```
(client/get
  "http://yoursite.com/some-url"
  {:query-params {"status" [1 2 3]}
   :debug true})
```

Comment: I think it works with any HTTP method - you can easily check it.